# how to autoresize iframe contents on extjs webdesktop

Tags: extjs, managed, javascript, iframe

i'm creating my personal extjs webdesktop , i have a tab panel with a tab where i wrote html code for iframe that load a aspx page.

When i resize window tabpanel iframe contents doesn't resize like a browser does and i see just scroll bars,is it possible autoresize iframe contents also?
 here there is my code:

```
 items: [{



                        title: 'Tab Text 1',

                        html : '<p><iframe src ="newadmin.aspx" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder=0></ iframe></p>'

                    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    title: 'TITLE',
    width: 450,
    height:190,
    renderTo: 'remotecontrol',
    layout:'fit',
    constrain:true,
    items:[{
    xtype : "component",
    autoEl:{
    tag:'iframe',
    src :'Your URL'
    }
    }]
});
```

`constrain:true` this will helps to auto resize

Answer (score 0):

Are all the elements dimensions inside newadmin.aspx defined as 'x%' ?

Comment: When you need clarification, it's better to add a comment to the original question instead of posting your question as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

That iframe cannot be resized by its ExtJS parent component, because Ext positioning and sizing is not as simple as you think.

But instead of learning a lot of Ext internals, you could simply use the following UX (user extension) which handles your particular problem (among other things): **[Ext.ux.ManagedIframe](http://code.google.com/p/managediframe/)**